# Suspend on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: 20.04, suspend, laptop, toshiba-satellite

I did a fresh install on a Toshiba's laptop without dualboot, only Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on legacy mode. Everything works great, except when I want to open lid after suspend.

When I close the lid, the laptop goes to suspend and works but when I open it to wake up, is works too, but 30 seconds later falling on suspend state again (with lid open). To stop this, I need to restart. After restart, laptop works well, until next suspend and the whole things repeats again.

Do you have an idea to fix that?
I tried to check on settings but nothing changed except to cancel suspend state when lid is closed on tweak.

Toshiba Satellite P845T - 10Z

OS : Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue on my Dell Inspiron 15 5593.
These are the fixes I tried but to no avail. Maybe they will work for you.

**FIX 1**

- `sudoedit /etc/default/grub`
- find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LIUNX_DEFAULT` and add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.
- `sudo update-grub`
- reboot

**FIX 2**

- `sudoedit /etc/default/grub`
- find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add `nomodeset` at the end of the line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.
- `sudo update-grub`
- reboot

I'm still looking for a fix for my device so let us know if any of these work.

Comment: Thanks @girreus to help me to find a solution. FIX 1 didn't worked. Nothing change at all. FIX 2 gave me some lag on my laptop without resolving issue. To be more specific, it canceled suspend state when lid was down.